# Lack of understanding when fread a file into an array

Tags: c, file, cs50, fread, uint8t

I'm doing CS50 (Week 4 Lab 4 Volume) and I have to copy a header from an input WAV file to output file (the 44 first bytes).

To start, I created the array `uint8_t header[HEADER_SIZE];`. Then, I used `fread`. But why the right solution is : `fread(header, HEADER_SIZE, 1, input);` and not something like : `fread(header, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, input);`?

Don't it mean that all the header will be copied at once in the `header` array in a single element (which will lead to an error since an element must have 1 byte due to its type `uint8_t`)? Does the compiler now how to handle the situation when reading at once many bytes into an array with only 1 byte per element?

Thank you!

Comment: It could be. But here you need to read the whole header, so the element size is `HEADER_SIZE` and the number of elements is `1`. The difference is that on success, `fread` with return `1` and `HEADER_SIZE` respectively.

Comment: Who says the second one is wrong?  Did you try it?

Comment: You can read 1 item of size `HEADER_SIZE` or `HEADER_SIZE` items of size 1. What's the difference in the end? Besides of course, return value of `fread` will be different.

Comment: @Gerhardh there is a difference if you handle partial reads. You ask for 100 elements of size 1 and get 50 back, you are happy. But if you ask for 1 element of size 100, you cannot get ½ back.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes, thank you. But why is the 1st option still correct since the `header` array must contain elements of type `uint8_t` (1byte)? Will the compiler break for us the header every byte?

Comment: The bytes in the header correspond  with the bytes in the file 1-to-1.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That might apply to cases where you read multiple items and only get half of them. If you read half a header I am not sure if you really will be happy.

Comment: The bytes read from the file will not be stored in the first element but within the whole array.

Comment: @stark I've just done it and my `header` array remains the same. Thank you! Can I assume that the compiler "breaks down" for the 44 bytes in single bytes in the 1st case?

Comment: Note that `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1 (by definition). So, using it in calculations is deprecated. A little tricky with `sizeof(uint8_t)` but don't use for the same reason. Strictly speaking, `fread(header,sizeof(header),1,input)` _might_ be the best, but ... In `glibc` [linux], the `size` and `nmemb` are multiplied together as the first line of `fread`: `size_t bytes_requested = size * count;` and that is used internally. So, it's a bit of a moot point. `read` (the syscall) uses a byte count, so I do: `fread(header,1,sizeof(header),input)` to get a byte count return value